# Django-admin: MoneyField doesn't show currency

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-1.10

I have a model `Product` and model `Price`. The `Price` has a `ForeignKey(Product...)` and `original_price` and `eur_price` which are `MoneyField`'s (Django-money). So one `Product` object can have multiple `Price` objects related.

I tried to inline the `Price` objects into `Product` model admin which works correctly, but when I set original_price and eur_price to be `readonly_fields`, it shows amounts but not currencies.

This is without making them `readonly`:

```
class PriceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Price
    max_num = 10
    #readonly_fields = ('original_price','eur_price')


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ScanInline,]
```

[image]

And this with readonly:

```
class PriceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Price
    max_num = 10
    readonly_fields = ('original_price','eur_price')


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ScanInline,]
```

[image]

Do you have any idea how to show currency there if those fields are readonly?

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this:

```
class PriceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Price
    max_num = 10
    readonly_fields = ('get_original_price','get_eur_price')

    def get_original_price(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('&euro;{}'.format(obj.original_price))

    def get_eur_price(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('&euro;{}'.format(obj.eur_price))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this happens if you do it in admin. Can you instead try to override the form?

```
class PriceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Price
    max_num = 10

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(PriceInline, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['original_price'].disabled = True

        return form
```